# how can I listen a variable change in a open dialog with angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dialog

I have a boolean variable named isTrue. When all data came in my list from api isTrue turn true. Also I have open dialog when page is loaded. I want to show close button in this dialog when isTrue = true. It is kinda loader I think. While isTrue = false my exit button has to be disappear. When it turns true my exit button should be active. But in my code it takes data only once and can't see when isTrue change

note: I am using angular cli 9.1.9

```
const dialogconfig = new MatDialogConfig()
dialogConfig.data = this.isTrue
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open("loaderComponent", dialogConfig)
```

Comment: using a service to communicate? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service

Comment: I can use dialogRef.disableClose too. But I can not check that simultaneously

Comment: I don't understand the comment? What does the closing of dialog have to do with my suggestion of using a service?

Comment: I was just hoping using dialogRef.disableClose will solve my problem without a service. But I got the point. I have to subscribe for tracking changes